# How to use hooks in correct way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have some issue

1- I defined a function that gets data from API and calling it in `useEffect`, It's work well
But i got this warning in VScode.

> React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getOpenOrders'.
> Either include it or remove the dependency array.

2- I implement pagination in the FlatList, So when the user reached the end of data List I calling a function to increment the current page, and based on current page updated, `getOpenOrders` fetched again because i pass `currentPage` to useEffect to the dependency array

So the issue here is in `getOpenOrders` should be contacted previous data with the new data so I use `Concat` method,

It's work well But some time I got a warning tells me there an duplicated data,
And when I use spread `[...old, new]` not work and I got a big error because Flatlist keyExtractor issue or something,

So can any hero here review my code and tell me what the wrong here with issue **`1 - 2`**

code snippet

```
const OpenedAppointments = () => {

  const [openedAppointment, setOpenedAppointment] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [lastPage, setLastPage] = useState(1);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isFetch, setIsFetch] = useState(false);




 const loadMoreOrders = () => {
    if (currentPage <= lastPage - 1) {
      setLoading(true);
      setCurrentPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
      console.log('loadMore??');
    }
  };

  const _renderFooter = () => {
    return loading ? (
      <View
        style={{
          paddingVertical: 10,
        }}>
        <ActivityIndicator color="#000000" size="large" />
      </View>
    ) : null;
  };
  const getOpenOrders = () => {
    let AuthStr =
      'Bearer ,,,,';

    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: AuthStr,
    };
    Api.post(
      `/open_orders?page=${currentPage}`,
      {},
      {
        headers,
      },
    )
      .then((res) => {
        let last_Page = res.data.open_orders.last_page;
        let allOpenedOrders = res.data.open_orders.data;
        console.log('res:', allOpenedOrders);
        console.log('last_Page', last_Page);
        setLastPage(last_Page);
        setOpenedAppointment((prevOpenedOrders) =>
          prevOpenedOrders.concat(allOpenedOrders),
        ); // issue 2

        // setOpenedAppointment((prevOpenedOrders) =>[...prevOpenedOrders, allOpenedOrders]);
        setLoading(false);

    // For pull to refresh
        setIsFetch(false);

      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('err', err));
  };
// For pull to refresh
const _refresh = () => {
    setIsFetch(true);
    getOpenOrders();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getOpenOrders();
  }, [currentPage]); // warning here "issue 1"

  return (
    <FlatList
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
      data={openedAppointment}
      ListEmptyComponent={renderEmpty}
      renderItem={renderItems}
      keyExtractor={(item,index) => String(index)}
      ListFooterComponent={_renderFooter}
      onEndReached={loadMoreOrders}
      onEndReachedThreshold={1}

    // For pull to refresh
      onRefresh={_refresh}
      refreshing={isFetch}
    />
  );
};

export default OpenedAppointments;
```

Comment: For first question, maybe you could declare `getOpenOrders` inside your useEffect.

Comment: @鄭元傑 yes that disappears the warning, but is it the good way to declare every function i have inside the`useEffect` itself? Maybe will be code is messy!

Comment: I cannot tell you why react useEffect linter suggest to do that. But from my personal coding opinion, I think it's good practice to put everything just to the proper scope.  The outside function doesn't need to use the function. When others read your code, maybe they would wonder "hmm, I read this function declare here maybe it would be used later but actually it's only called in the useEffect". I think this is mentioned in 《Clean Code》

Answer (score 2):

For Issue 1:

- either add the dependency to the array:

  ```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getOpenOrders();
  }, [currentPage, getOpenOrders]);
  ```
- or use eslint rule as answered by @Matt Aft, It wont make a difference for your usecase

For issue 2:
I would suggest removing duplicates with a Set:

```
   setOpenedAppointment((prevOpenedOrders) =>
      Array.from(new Set([...prevOpenedOrders, ...allOpenedOrders]))
    );
```

This will concat your new Orders and your old Orders with spread syntax (...) and will remove duplicates by creating a new Set. (Sets allow only unique items, therefore will remove duplicates. Then you convert it back to an Array with Array.from so you can use it as before

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answering, for contacting array i'm using it as you said but it's still  got this warning `Encountered two children with the same key, `2`.` i don't know why!

And as I said to @Malt when I set getOpenOrders to dependency array the linter tell me to wrape it with `useCallBack` so I want to know what the benefits of it?

Comment: Did you check if any of your items acutally have the same key?

Comment: Using useCallback is for performance optimization and helps react to understand your flow of state and dependecies in your logic. Can you wrap your getOpenOrders in a useCallback and add all dependencies to it that it needs? what happens to your warn message?

Comment: Yes it's has a deference key, I guess this issue because `Fast Refresh`!
For `useCallback`, yes after used it the message warning disappeared!

Comment: after defining keyExtractor outside FlatList like this `const keyExtractor = (item, index) => String(index);` it's solve the keys issue.
Can you please check this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720438/how-to-use-hooks-in-correct-way/63720669?noredirect=1#comment112700493_63720669)?

Comment: Hey @jpmarks, are you check it? Because also your workaround for issue 2 not get the updated data when pull to refresh too 

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the spread operator on the second array:

```
setOpenedAppointment((prevOpenedOrders) =>[...prevOpenedOrders, ...allOpenedOrders]);
```

also issue 1 is because of the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule you have enabled, basically there are two ways you can fix this:

1. wrap `getOpenOrders` in a `useCallback` and add it to the dep array in the `useEffect`
2. disable the linter for that line

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
   getOpenOrders();
 // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
 }, [currentPage]);
```

Comment: Hey @MaltAft, yes, you're right i think just we add spread operator for the first array ,
for disabling the linter it's good but I want to know why should I use `useCallbake` what the benefits of it?

Comment: @OliverD useCallback returns a memoized function.

Comment: @OliverD so that liter requires all dependencies to be listed in the array, in your case you would need to add `getOpenOrders`, the way you have it gets redefined on every re-render which will trigger the useEffect and cause an infinite loop. `useCallback` will memoize the function so on re-renders it remains the same value and doesn't trigger the `useEffect`

Comment: another option is also if you're only going to use `getOpenOrders` in the `useEffect` then just define & call it in there and you won't need to use `useCallback` or add it to the dep array

Comment: Yes i got it, thank you! Now if we back to concat arrays, now I implement "Pull to refresh" to get the updated data now after I updated the order then pull to refresh i couldn't get the new updated for this order, it's still old data

Comment: @MattAft I Edit the question to add the pull to refresh stuff can you please take a look?
Note: when I just add `setOpenedAppointment(allOpenedOrders);` "for Testing", I got the updated data But that's way canceled the pagination concept!

Comment: why dont you keep it as `setOpenedAppointment((prevOpenedOrders) =>[...prevOpenedOrders, ...allOpenedOrders]);`? @OliverD

Comment: I'm already keep it like this, but i could not get the updated data! I don't know why! Although when i log `allOpenedOrders` i can see the new updated data!